# From Salesforce JIRA issue will Automatically Create

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I want to set the some condition in Salesforce CASE.

Whenever user click on the "CREATE JIRA" button in case, the JIRA issue will automatically create into the JIRA tool.

It is possible to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

It should be possible by using the REST api provided by JIRA for this.
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/